# How to compare data from firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do a user validation system. I need to ask if the parameters i enter are the same with the ones register in Firebase.

[image: My firebase collection]

I tried to do this but it fails.

```
Future<bool> verificarCredenciales(int legajo, int pass) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  CollectionReference usuarios =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Legajos');

  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await usuarios
      .where('Legajo', isEqualTo: legajo)
      .where('Pass', isEqualTo: pass)
      .get();

  return snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty;
}
```

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    bool credencialesValidas =
        await verificarCredenciales(legajo, pass);
    if (credencialesValidas) {
      showToast('Usuario permitido');
      navigatorKey.currentState?.pushReplacementNamed('/register');
    } else {
      showToast('Legajo o contraseña incorrectos');
    }
  },
  child: const Text('Ingresar'),
)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please dont post images of the code. rather, you can [edit] your question to include them as a code snippet

Comment: The code you shared looks fine at first glance, but it's hard to help with "it fails". If you run this code, what exactly doesn't work about it and what does it do instead? Is there an error message?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.